# Sum of all subsets in the range

Tags: segment-tree

Given an array A consisting of N elements and Q queries of type [l,r]. Print the sum of all possible subsets in the range [l,r].
Example: A[]= { 1, 2, 3 } & l= 1, r= 3;
Sol: print {1}, {2}, {3}, {1+2}, {1+3}, {2+3}, {1+2+3}

P.S I am using Segment trees with bit manipulation to find the sum of all possible subsets but it will give tle. Is there any optimized solution?

Comment: Check this out http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-possible-combinations-of-r-elements-in-a-given-array-of-size-n/

Comment: @maximusツ it will give tle in programming contests.